# Chrome debugger extension displays all breakpoints as unbound

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am debuging my application using Visual Studio Code.

After running `ng serve` I am able to set the breakpoints.
However after I run my debug chrome configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
   
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            
        },
   ]
}
```

... all breakpoins are unbound, why?.
Am I missing something in my configuration files?
I don't understand if `ng serve` compiles the files and does not have any problems setting breakpoints why chrome extension does?
I am using VS Code Version: 1.85.1.